# Redirecionamento 503 em várias URLs com exceção de uma

Tags: php, htaccess, redirecionamento

Como fazer um redirect 503 (código de manutenção) em todo site, mas deixar somente uma URL com possibilidade de acesso?

Servidor: Linux (Apache) com PHP 5.5 e MySQL.

Comment: Servidor Linux (Apache) - PHP 5.5 e MySQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ponha no `.htaccess` (ou configuração do apache):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/caminho/permitido.html
RewriteRule .* /erro503.php
```

A `!` no `RewriteCond` significa negação, ou seja, a condição é que o caminho **não** seja o indicado em seguida, para que o `RewriteRule` entre em ação.

Este é o script `erro503.php`:

```php
<?php
   header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
   header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
   header('Retry-After: 3600');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
   <title>Servi&ccedil;o Temporariamente Indispon&iacute;vel</title>
</head><body>
   <h1>Servi&ccedil;o Temporariamente Indispon&iacute;vel</h1>
   <p>(Ponha sua explicacao aqui).</p>
</body></html>
```

- mude o valor de `Retry-After` para o tempo desejado em segundos (pró-forma, na prática acho que nenhum *agent* usa esse valor)
- o header `Status` só é necessário se usar o PHP como CGI.

Comment: Entendi Bacco. No caso então, permitido.html vai ser a única acessível, correto?

Comment: Exatamente. Teste e conte o resultado, se precisar ajustamos.